# Create a list of elements

Tags: javascript

I want to create a list of recognized notes, but have an issue to do this. The note just changing one to another one.

index.html

```
<p id="message"></p>
```

app.js

```
var message = document.querySelector('#message');

song.addEventListener('ended', ()=>{
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        var last = event.results.length - 1;
        var command = event.results[last][0].transcript;
        message.textContent = command + '.'; 
    }
    recognition.start();
})
```

Comment: Could you please add complete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add each recognized phrase in a new line, you can replace

```
message.textContent = command + '.';
```

with

```
message.innerHTML += command + '.<br>';
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, I also tried appendChild but it also didn't work, seems like I need to use array to put results in and then extract them by doing forEach()

Comment: @JohnPix Can you post the rest of the code (html + js) and a sample of your data?

Comment: @JohnPix if you do what you describe in your last comment, if you have synchronization errors, you can end up having your items in a messed up order. In what sense does your code not work? It shows only one item? Or it shows just dots?

Comment: thanks, but the problem here now that it starts playing song and starts recognition at the same time and it recognizes words from the end of the song, not my speech. It doesn't wait the end of the song.

Comment: @JohnPix oh, I thought you were trying to recognize the "songs", I didn't have a mic plugged. The songs are instructions, eh? I used my mic now, and doing `message.innerHTML += command + '.<br>';` added each thing I said between the "songs" in a new line.

Comment: yep, they are instructions)